# (How To) Check the value of my sys.path by logging the value to a temporary file

Tags: django

So I've had a problem with my PYTHONPATH lately.

I've been told to "check the value of sys.path explicitly at the beginning of the settings.py file and log the value to a temporary file".

In semi-laymans terms, how is this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your settings.py, assuming Python 2.6 or newer:

```
import sys
with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    f.write(sys.path)
```

Or you could "print sys.path" if you were using runserver, and see the value in the console output.